# Sending email in PHP with a checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How would one send an email from emails coming in from a database? but allowing the user to tick a checkbox stating  send to all when checkbox is clicked. How would i store these emails in the checkbox and how would i pass them onto the the mailing function

```
<?php   
    $query="SELECT emails FROM users";
    $result=mysqli_query($db,$query);
    while($email=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $email=$email['student_email'];
    }
?>
    <input type ="checkbox " name="$email[]" value="" />
```

how could i use this $email within a checkbox so that all emails will be stored there?Or is there a different way to do this?
 thanks guys

Comment: You are mixing PHP and HTML code, you should enclose your PHP inside `<?php` and `?>`.

Comment: Don't mix Database access and HTML generation like that. Seperate them. MVC Frameworks such as Symfony and Flow will help you.

Comment: First, write a code to print the emails of checked emails. Second, write code send email from php. Thrid, put these two things together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply normalized your code and added the requested feature:

```
<?php
$query  = "SELECT emails FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

while ($email = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="mails[]" value="' . $email['student_email'] . '" />', PHP_EOL;
}
```

After submitting:

```
<?php
foreach ($_REQUEST['mails'] as $studentMail) {
    echo $studentMail . '<br>', PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Update:**

I missunderstood your question.

If you want to send a mail to all users, you woulnd't put in the mails at all:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="send-to-all" value="yes">
```

Then after submitting:

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['send-to-all']) && $_REQUEST['send-to-all'] == 'yes') {
    $query  = "SELECT emails FROM users";
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
    while ($email = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        // send email here or gather array to send a single mail to all
    }
}
```

If you want to include groups, I'd do it this way:

```
<input type="hidden" name="groups" value="<?php echo json_encode($groups); ?>" />
```

Comment: works great thanks.but i only want to show one checkbox and at moment its showing checkboxes for all emails

Comment: @FrancescoMM should i use an array? as it has to send to an entire group, not just one

Comment: @DanFromGermany , thanks dan works great. if i want to  send email to certain groups. All i do is change the name attribute of the checkbox?   <input type="checkbox" name="gamers[]" value="yes">Tick   <input type="checkbox" name="food[]" value="yes">Tick

Comment: @jackmonreo no, no need for an array if you don't pass all the emails

Comment: I'd include the ID's of the groups in a serialized field, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
while($email=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $email=$email['student_email'];
  echo '<input type ="checkbox " name="$email" />';
}
```

and then submit the form to a page which foreaches the post values and mails all of the emails

Answer (score 0):

You can make like:

```
<?php
    $result = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT id, student_email FROM users');
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            var_dump($_POST['email-' . $row['id']]);
            if($_POST['email-' . $row['id']]){
                //Send
            }else{
                //Not send
            }
        }
    }
?>
<form method="post">
    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="email-<?=$row['id']?>" value="" />
    <?php endwhile;?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: OP is using `mysqli_` and not `mysql_`

Comment: I using PDO, this is demo

Comment: Don't give pseudo-code, it's not the API that the OP is using.

Comment: `short_open_tags` are off by default on most servers (`<?=$var;?>`)

Comment: I noticed your edit. You can't mix MySQL APIs with `mysqli_query` and `mysql_fetch_array` they must all be `mysqli_` functions. Plus `$result = mysqli_query('SELECT id, student_email FROM users');` should contain DB connection `$result = mysqli_query($db,'SELECT id, student_email FROM users');`

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you want to send the e-mails with a single checkbox. First of all don't forget to wrap your input into a `<form id="..." method="..." action="...">...</form>` tag group. You don't have to pass the returned mysql result to the input as a name attribute, because  if you check that checkbox, then submitting the form, you must do one thing: send the emails. So I would only set a the name of the input to "send". After that you can check in your php code:

```
<?php
  //I assume, that you used post method
  if($_POST['send']){
    foreach($email as $mail){
      mail($mail, $subject, $msg);
    }
  }
?>
```

I hope it helps you.